# Add a text to specifics <p> from a list created with php

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop

I'm stuck with this. I have a UL (created with PHP while) with a list of LI (every LI represents a month) and inside of this LIs I need to append a P element with a Text (Year). The thing is that I have to append this text just a specifics LI (January) to announce that a new year come in the list. So when you scroll you can see "January 2018, February... January 2019..."

The other thing that I need is that every new "January" must have +1 year according to the year before. This calendar is not in real time, it could show for example 2016-2018, But always gonna have the data of the first year, provided by the user.

I could  add the P element to every LI that have the word 'January' with $('contains:"January"'). html () but i don't know how to increase the Year and make a loop on it.

Any idea?

Here is the code and now is not working:

```
                    <?php
                      $yearAdd=1;
                      $meses = array("ENERO","FEBRERO","MARZO","ABRIL","MAYO","JUNIO","JULIO","AGOSTO","SEPTIEMBRE","OCTUBRE","NOVIEMBRE","DICIEMBRE");
                      $mesInicial=($excel_arr2 [$primerFilaEtapa] ['G']);
                      $mesExplode= explode("/", $mesInicial);
                      $anio=$mesExplode[2];
                      $mesTexto =  $meses [$mesNumero-2 + $primerMes];    
                      while ($yearAdd <= 4) { 
                        if ($mesTexto === 'ENERO'){ 
                        $anioTabla= $anio + $yearAdd;?>
                        <script>                               
                          var year2 = "<p class='font-year'></p>";
                          $('p:contains("ENERO")').after(year2);
                          $('.font-year').html('<?php echo $anioTabla;?>');        
                        </script> 
                      <?php   }                           
                     $yearAdd++; }
                     ?>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Paste some code!

Comment: Do it directly in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time paste your code 'what / how you were tried', the community members can assist you very quickly.

Try this:

```js
var start_year = 2018; // you can define the start year however you need
$( "li:contains('January')" ).each(function(){
 $(this).append('<p>'+start_year+'</p>');
   ++start_year;
})
```

```html
<ul>
<li>January</li>
<li>Feb</li>
.
.
.
.
<li>Dec</li>
<li>January</li>
<li>Feb</li>
.
.
.
.
<li>Dec</li>
<li>January</li>
<li>Feb</li>
.
.
.
.
<li>Dec</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh Man! that's works like a charm! Thank you so much!!